# Getting HttpErrorResponse error in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to send http post request from my createorder.component.ts page to create a record. But I am getting HttpErrorResponse error. Where I am doing wrong? please help

**createorder.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(form: any) {
this.spinner.show();
 this.http.post('/api/order/' + '_foodforest' + '/' + '9ed7f9d5-8ed3-4f57-b360-7e4da87f2d6d' ,
      JSON.stringify(form.value))
      .subscribe(result => {
this.spinner.hide();
});
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Try `form.value` instead of `JSON.stringify(form.value))`

Comment: I tried by adding form.value, but it getting same error @KamranKhatti

Comment: Looks like the end point you are making call has something wrong at back end side check server side, for debugging purpose return static value in response form server.

Comment: I am calling router.POST("/api/order/:namespace/:orgid", order.CreateOrderHandler)
my backend side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular HttpClient try to parse the api response into `JSON` by default.

Your API response is not in a JSON format and `JSON.parse` is failed inside `HttpClient`.

You can return the api response as JSON from backend or should tell the http client that the type of resposne is not a JSON:

```js
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(form.value), {
  responseType: 'text'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmit(form: any) {
  const url=''; // replace with your endpoint
  const headers = new Headers();
  // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
  this.spinner.show();
  this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(form.value), { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(result => {this.spinner.hide();});
}
```

Try the above code snippet with content type you required text/plain or application/x-www-form-urlencoded